# Why are chunks of my Sedum Spectabile snapping off at the stem bases?

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, perennials, damage, sedum

Whole chunks of my sedum plant (which looks otherwise healthy) come away in my hand because the stem has snapped/cut clean through. What's causing this, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Definitely need pictures.  Adding this link for basic care of Sedum spectabile.  You might be overwatering?http://plantfacts.osu.edu/pdf/0247-1029.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me when the plants are growing too soft. Reasons for this can include:

- Too much water
- Too much fertilizer
- Not enough light

These plants can become very fragile when the conditions are too 'good'. In my area, even specimens growing in full sun, in dry, poor soil (what these plants need) can fall apart in a heavy rainstorm.

Wherever your plant is, it seems that one or more of these conditions is off. Make sure it gets as much sun as possible (over 8 consecutive hours is ideal, so the stems can become fibrous and less fragile), and if it's in damp or rich soil, consider moving it to a dryer, or poorer soil. Not like fill dirt bad, but not as rich as your average garden loam.

Comment: Thanks, that could well be it. I've been watering it regularly since it was planted about a month ago. I've also been feeding it approx once a week, and I planted it with compost and fertiliser, and it only gets sun from about 1pm!